# How to build hadoop1.0.4 eclipse plug-in from build.xml file?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hadoop-plugins

I have to write MapReduce programs for Hadoop1.0.4 in Eclipse.

This version of Hadoop does not contain plug-in for eclipse.

However the build.xml file can be found in $HADOOP_HOME/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin.

How do I generate or build the plug-in for eclipse from the build.xml file?

Answer (score 1):

vi into build.xml file. the default argument is jar 
I did `$HADOOP_HOME/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin: ant jar`  and was expecting the plugin.jar file but it says build failed because of autoconf . 
Look at these for reference 
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipsePlugIn
http://rohanlopes.blogspot.com/2012/08/download-hadoop-103-plugin-for-eclipse.html
http://linuxjunkiemonkey.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/eclipse-apache-hadoop-plugin-build-1-0-2/

I tied getting the plugin.jar file for 2 days and I finally had to roll back to 0.20.2 . Please let me know how you got the build working or please send me the hadoop1.0.4-eclipse-plugin.jar if its working for you.

Comment: May be you are not a su,or the eclipse_home is not set

Comment: I ran it sudo it says BUILD SUCCESSFUL but I still dont see the jar in the build/ dir. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

open the build.xml file

search for:

```
<fileset dir="${eclipse.home}/plugins/">
```

replace ${eclipse.home} with the real path

open your terminal.

cd to $HADOOP_HOME/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin

$ sudo ant jar

It will create some jar files in the folders described in the build.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the build.xml to have eclipse.home env variable set. You can compile it in two ways at least,

1) under linux env, you build the hadoop common first. Then, you set eclipse.home to have eclipse plugin to be compiled.

2) you modify build.xml to point to binary hadoop jar files and set eclipse.home. then, you build eclipse plugin.

You can also download build jar file from here: http://yiyujia.blogspot.com/2012/10/eclipse-mapreduce-plugin-build-for.html .